# Основы работы с блокнотом Jupiter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Только приступил к изучению  программирования и при запуске блокнота Jupiter в отличии от видеокурса который просматриваю, у меня вместо строк in и out отображается латинская В. Прошу подсказать нужно ли выполнить какие ни будь дополнительные настройки или это такой апгрейд, и мне не нужно обращать на это внимание. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: приложите ссылку на курс и скриншот того что вас не устраивает, а то так сложно понять

Comment: Это ошибка перевода интерфейса jupyter - "В" это одновременно "ввод" и "вывод". Должно переводиться по-разному. Но на работу это никак не влияет, можно не обращать внимания. По идее можно отключить перевод интерфейса.

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет, Jupyter это софт для абстрактного макетирования. Совсем не подходящая штука для изучения программирования. Её используют программисты-инженеры, для того что-бы сделать абстрактный макет проекта или модуля.

Comment: спасибо, не рискнул просто двигаться дальше без понимания на что может повлиять

Comment: Для изучения программирования могу посоветовать 3 вещи. 1. Lua - язык программирования цель которого быть понятным не для программистов. 2. Python - Посложнее но уже используется в проф. программировании - его первая идеология - просто и понятно значит хорошо. 3. Простые вэб языки Node (Javascript)/PHP такие языки тебе помогут близко приблизится к синтаксису более сложных языков таких как Java и C++

Comment: @EugeneX, не знаю что вы имеете в виду под абстрактным макетированием, но Jupyter - это среда интерактивного выполнения (REPL, например, для Python) в веб-интерфейсе с возможностью повторного запуска ранее выполненных команд, отображением данных в графическом виде (изображений, графиков, данных табличном виде). Для обучения программированию в какой-то степени подходит, для макетирования проектов или модулей - не очень (максимум - для быстрой проверки работоспособности кусков кода).

Comment: Абстрактное макетирование это - когда ещё до конца не понимаешь как программа должна делать свою работу, и надо заранее примерно накидать код что-бы понять шаги выполнения. По поводу онлайн компиляторов могу посоветовать OnlineGDB - https://www.onlinegdb.com/ . В правом верхнем углу выбираешь язык программирования, и прям на сайте пишешь код. Это порт всем известного GCC (Genue C Complier).

Comment: спасибо всем, приятно что есть люди которые делятся опытом, думал таких уже нет. сам инвестиционный аналитик и  всегда делюсь своими навыками. Очень рад что есть такое сообщество!!! Оплатил курс skilbox, но вижу очень много недостатков.

Comment: У программистов в сообществе всегда так, нам всегда приходится работать в команде и очень много обмениваться опытом. Индустрия очень быстро растущая и если выпасть хоть чуть чуть из потока - приходиться очень много и болезненно навёрстывать. Обращайтесь - с радостью поможем! Без помощи обычно остаются только студенты двоечники, которые уже достали своими просьбами за них написать код. :-)